# Attaching .msg File Using addFileAttachmentAsync Fails

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am working on a project where we are attempting to attach a variety of documents to a draft email via an outlook add-in created in *React*/*TypeScript*. Basically, we have the following code snippet that we're using to add files as attachments to the current email draft:

```
     public attachFile(fileUrl: string, filename: string): Promise<Office.AsyncResult<any>> {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            (Office.context.mailbox.item as any).addFileAttachmentAsync(
                fileUrl,
                filename,
                { asyncContext: null },
                (attachResult: Office.AsyncResult<any>) => {
                    resolve(attachResult);
                }
            );
        });
    }
```

Now typically, when this function is fired it looks something like this:

```
const outlookApp = this.officeApp as OutlookOfficeApp;
const attachResult = await outlookApp.attachFile(attachUrl, fileName);
```

In an example where this works, the file name would be `Document 1.docx` - but this function consistently fails for `.msg` files.

When attempting to attach a `.msg` file, from the `attachResult` it would appear that the attachment did not fail since this is the result we get back:
[image: AttachResult Object]

But, when we inspect if the attachment failed by using the following function (with the `value` property that is returned on the `attachResult` object:

```
     public async didAttachFail(attachmentOutlookId: string): Promise<boolean> {
        const attachments = await new Promise(async results => {
            const mailboxItem = Office.context.mailbox.item;
            const options = { asyncContext: { currentItem: mailboxItem } };
            Office.context.mailbox.item.getAttachmentsAsync(
                options,
                (response: Office.AsyncResult<Office.AttachmentDetails[]>) => {
                    results(response);
                }
            );
        });
        // Atachments will have 0 size if they failed to download
        return (attachments as Office.AsyncResult<Office.AttachmentDetails[]>).value.some(
            x => x.id === attachmentOutlookId && x.size === 0
        );
    }
```

It would appear that the size of the item is 0 - which in turn means it did not attach correctly. When downloading the file from the `fileUrl` specified for `addFileAttachmentAsync` (which I've done to confirm that the URL supplied works), I can clearly see that the item is not 0KB;

[image: Message File Size]

Is there anything we're doing wrong when it comes to the attachment of `.msg` files, or is there another way of doing this? The outlined code works for a variety of other content types, including Word documents, images, PowerPoint, and Excel files. It only fails for Outlook messages/`.msg` files.

****Edit 1:**
I'm using the Outlook app on my desktop (Version 2005, Build 12827.20268), my `Windows version is 1909` (Build 18363.900). I've also tested this in Outlook Online, in Chrome (Version 83.0.4103.97) and Microsoft Edge (Version 83.0.478.45) with the same results.

****Edit 2:**

- I am able to manually add this .msg file manually.
- Additionally, there are no errors when attaching the debugger (and that makes sense, the attachment's size is 0 when looking at the output of using `addFileAttachmentAsync`).
- So the last call was to test everything using Script Lab (thanks for the reminder on this one) and;

Here are the .yaml for the script I created: https://gist.github.com/svbygoibear/9febca6eeaca5748d15995dd879cae64#file-add-attachments-outlook-outlook-yaml

Now here I've made a whole bunch of sample documents (one image, one .docx and one .msg file) to test `addFileAttachmentAsync`. All the files (including the .msg file) attaches correctly, but if you see the output from the last method (which is the `getAttachmentsAsync`) you will see that the .msg files' size is 0:

[image]

We use this to check if files have been correctly attached - so it seems that the issue is with `getAttachmentsAsync`. Is it expected to return a 0 size for .msg files?

Comment: What Outlook platform are you facing this issue on?

Comment: Ah let me add all the version numbers in the original question - but I'm using the Outlook app on my desktop (Version 2005, Build 12827.20268), my Windows version is 1909 (Build 18363.900).

I've also tested this in Outlook Online, in Chrome (Version 83.0.4103.97) and Microsoft Edge (Version 83.0.478.45) with the same results.

Comment: We are unable to repro this issue. Are you able to attach this file manually?

Comment: Can you repro this in ScriptLab? Scriplab is an add-in for Outlook, which is available in the store. Instructions for installing add-ins from the store can be found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-an-office-add-in-for-outlook-1ee261f9-49bf-4ba6-b3e2-2ba7bcab64c8?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#:~:text=Install%20an%20add%2Din%20from,want%2C%20review%20its%20privacy%20polic).

In this add-in, there are sample snippets, such as "Manipulate attachments (Item Compose)" , that can be used to try to repro this issue.

Comment: You can also [try attaching a debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10) to see any issues with the add-in.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions! I've edited the question above with all the additional answers, but:
- I'm able to manually
- I've tried the same in Script Lab - it actually works but I did notice something else (I'm adding it in the description above).
- There are no errors in the debugger, the file attached however is 0KB in size even though if I look at the size of the original item passed through to addFileAttachmentAsync it is not.

Comment: Overall it looks like the issue is that when checking if the file is correctly attached (we do this by checking the size) - for .msg files the size is returned as 0 (which isn't correct in this case). So even though it does attach, the bit of code we have to confirm the size won't work since the size returned for .msg files isn't correct.

Comment: Could you confirm if the .msg is actually attached by manually opening the attached .msg to see if it opens.  Also could you check that after you send the message, recipients can open the attachment? I would like to confirm if it's an attaching issue or size reporting issue with the API.

Comment: I tested it with the script lab sample and it definitely attaches fine (I can open it up again in the message I'm editing and it opens up the .msg file perfectly fine) - it also works 100% (opening it that is) for recipients, so it looks like it is just the sizing that isn't 100% on the API's side. Also thank you for all the feedback/follow-ups :)

Comment: Thanks for the gist. I was able to repro the issue, with size = 0 on getFileAttachmentsAsync for .msg files. I have opened a bug on the product team's backlog to address this issue, but I have no timelines to share. I just want to confirm that the only issue you are currently seeing is size = 0, but the actual upload of the .msg file succeeds.

Comment: Thanks so much! Yup, that is correct - the upload works perfectly fine but it is the message size = 0 that is the problem I'm seeing on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this issue. After careful consideration, our team has decided to not fix this issue in the short term. We recommend you to upvote or create a new [Uservoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) item, this will give us visibility of the commonality of it and will help with our prioritization. If we end up working on this issue we will re-activate as needed.